# wysiwyg in custom module, image links are incorrect

Tags: image, wysiwyg

I have a custom module, where I want to add wysiwyg editor to field. 
I do it in this way:

```
    $fieldset->addField('submenu_html', 'editor', array(
        'name'      => 'submenu_html',
        'label'     => Mage::helper('cmsnav')->__('Submenu HTML'),
        'title'     => Mage::helper('cmsnav')->__('Submenu HTML'),
        'style'     => 'width:500px; height:400px;',
        'wysiwyg'   => true,
        'required'  => false,
        'config'    => Mage::getSingleton('cms/wysiwyg_config')->getConfig(),
    ));
```

In xml file I added all necessary JS and CSS files.
Editor is working, but then I upload image I get this kind of link:

```
<img src="http://linktoproject/index.php/admin/cms_wysiwyg/directive/___directive/e3ttZWRpYSB1cmw9Ind5c2l3eWcvVW50aXRsZWQtMS5wbmcifX0,/key/13e9709bba938ba67ff4ab68cb24c7a969aa89da4039bd850d65204116d6e76a/" alt="" />
```

And I can see image only in Mozilla, in other browsers image doesn't load.
I checked config setting which I get on my module page and in CMS Static Block, they are same. Where can be problem? Thank you.

Comment: Normally when someone says it loads only in one browser it makes me wonder if that's the browser you are logged in on and it's permissions related maybe?

Comment: Yes, I also think so, but I need to get correct link like this <img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/Untitled-1.png"}}" alt="" /> and where will be no problems with browsers.

Comment: In your custom module, how are you displaying your field in your template?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a browser issue. More than that, it's not a bug, it's a feature. You have the `Media Storage` set to `Database`. If you change that to `File System` you should see the image src like `{{media url="wysiwyg/Untitled-1.png"}}`.
You can change this setting from `System->Configuration->System->Storage Configuration for Media`